# Understanding mode and help on equals method

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 quick questions; here's my code. I'm confused on how that mode method works (it works). Also I need help on my equals method. Do I just make another array and see if they're equal, and how do I do that?

```
Public class Grades
{
    private int[] grade;
    private int highest, mode;
    private double average, median;

    public Grades(int n)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        grade = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            grade[i] = Math.abs(r.nextInt())%101;
    }

    public double getTotal()
    {
        int total = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < grade.length; i++)
            total += grade[i];
        return total;
    }

    public void calAverage()
    {
        average = getTotal()/(double) grade.length;
    }

    public int getHigh()
    {
        return highest;
    }

    public double getMedian()
    {
        return median;
    }

    public int getMode()
    {
        return mode;
    }

    public double getAverage()
    {
        return average;
    }

    public void highest()
    {
        highest = grade[grade.length - 1];
    }

    public void sort()
    {

        int i, j, t;
        for (i = 0; i < grade.length - 1; i++)
            for (j = i + 1; j < grade.length; j++)
                if (grade[i] > grade[j])
                {
                    t = grade[i];
                    grade[i] = grade[j];
                    grade[j] = t;
                }
    }

    public void calMedian()
    {

        if (grade.length%2 == 0)
            median = (grade[grade.length/2 - 1] + grade[(grade.length)/2])/2.;
        else
            median = grade[grade.length/2];
    }

    public void calMode()
    {
        int[] a = new int[101];
        int i, m;
        for (i = 0; i <= grade.length; i++)
            a[i] = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < grade.length; i++)
            a[grade[i]]++;
        m = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            if (a[i] > a[m])
                m = i;
        mode = m;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        int i;
        String s = "";
        for (i = 0; i < grade.length; i++)
        {
            s = s + grade[i] + " ";
            if ((i + 1)%10 == 0)
                s = s + '\n';
        }
        return s;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you write the mode method?

Comment: No the professor gave it to the whole class cause no one figured it out.

Comment: `calMode` is a confusing name. I would at least call it `calcMode` if not `calculateMode` (naming is hard :) same goes for `calAverage` and others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone ahead and explained the `mode()` method but I'm not sure what you're asking for in regards to an `equals()` method, if you can clarify I'll update my answer to include an explanation of that as well.

```
public void calMode()
{
    // This array will allow for indexes from 0 to 100 
    // (the same range as a grade on a 0-100 scale)
    int []a=new int[101];

    int i,m; // these are just temporary indexes

    // You don't need to do this, an int in java is set to 0 by default
    // as is an array of ints
    for(i=0;i<=grade.length;i++) 
         a[i]=0;

    // Here you are looking at each grade and incrementing the occurrences of each
    // where each index is the grade and the value stored at that index is the number
    // of times that grade appears
    for(i=0;i<grade.length;i++)
        a[grade[i]]++;
    m=0;

    // Here you are finding which grade has the highest frequency (the mode)
    // by comparing the values you calculated in the previous loop
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        if(a[i]>a[m])
            m=i;
        mode=m;
}
```

Comment: even I'm a bit confused on the equals nethod. I think what I want is should I make an equals method for seeing if two arrays are the same or if 2 numbers in one array are the same

Comment: Unfortunately I can't tell you what you want, but either way an equals method is fairly straightforward, if you're just comparing 2 numbers then it's as simple as `if(x==y) return true .. else return false`. If you're comparing arrays it's a matter of looping through each array simultaneously and comparing the values although you may need to sort them first.

Comment: @ArpitManaktala If I've helped answer your question(s), would you mind marking my answer as correct?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. The prof's calMode method works correctly if the data is unimodal. It will only return the mode with the lowest number if the data set is bimodal or multimodal. Take a look at http://www.mathsisfun.com/mode.html or think about what would happen with a data set like {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 9}, which has two modes, (2 and 5). The calMode method would only return a the lower mode of 2.